# Saving Type in localStorage works in development, but not in production

Tags: json, typescript, webpack

I tried to stringify a type, save it to localStorage and parse it again to create a dynamic component in Angular. The code is:

```
// panelTypes is a map of type: [ SomeComponent, AnotherComponent, ...]
private panelTypes: Type<DockablePanel>[];

// Stringifying
const saveString = JSON.stringify(this.dockTree, (key, value) => {
  if (key === 'type') {
    const panel: Type<DockablePanel> = this.panelTypes.find((panelType: Type<DockablePanel>) => {
      return panelType.name === value;
    });
    if (!panel) {
      console.log('Couldn\'t find paneltype ' + value);
    } else {
      return panel;
    }
  } else {
    return value;
  }
});

// Parsing
const stored = JSON.parse(storageItem, (key, value) => {
  if (key === 'type') {
    return value.name;
  } else {
    return value;
  }
});
```

This works when running in development, but in production the code gets obfuscated/minified, resulting in every value.name being something like 'e' or 'n'.

Is there a way to stringify and later parse a type in TypeScript? Do JavaScript classes have something I can use to identify types?

If not, is there a way to prevent certain values from being obfuscated/minified?

**[edit]**

I'm trying to store/restore a dynamic layout using Angular's ComponentFactoryResolver like this:

```
constructor(private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver,
          private dockerService: DockerService,
          private application: ApplicationRef,
          private changeDetector: ChangeDetectorRef) {
}

ngOnInit(): void {
    const componentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(this.panel.type);
    this.panelRef = this.dynamicInsert.createComponent(componentFactory);
}
```

DockTree is a tree consisting of two types of DockNodes: DockContainers and DockPanels:

```
export class DockTreeNode {
  parent: DockTreeContainer;
}

export class DockTreeContainer extends DockTreeNode {
  private orientation: Orientation;
  private left: DockTreeNode;
  private right: DockTreeNode;
}

export class DockTreePanel extends DockTreeNode {
  type: Type<DockablePanel>;
  args: DockArguments;
  movable: boolean;
  ref?: ViewRef;
}
```

So my tree looks like this:

[image]

Every panel node has a type field that should hold a Type. This type needs to be saved to localStorage, and later recovered from it. Minifiying gives me shortened nonsense classnames in Object.name though, so I can't use that.

Comment: It would be useful to understand what you trying to do. Store a tree of components and trying to recreate it afterwards? What is `this.dockTree`?

Comment: Yes I have a dynamic layout that I'm trying to save, and then recreate using Angular's ComponentFactoryResolver. I'll update my question and add an example of a DockTree.

Comment: You are using `webpack` for minification? If yes then you should see this thread https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2/issues/671

Comment: I will check. The solution in your link doesn't seem to cover my use case. I am working with dynamic components from a project that are used within a module. The names of these components are not known. I saw there is some way to use a regex, maybe I can use some naming convention.

Comment: To define which class obfuscated object belongs to you can try to use `object.constructor.name` property which usually is the same as object class name. Also you can add field with class name to your objects when stringify them